# How to run IntelliJ IDEA from its jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, ide

Today I want to make my IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate portable. I'm following this guide: http://leolabs.org/blog/making-intellij-portable/
Everything works. But now I want to make my portable IDEA runnable also from Linux & Mac OS. So I decided to create a run.sh file. But the question is, where is the executable jar, which I can use to run IntelliJ?
I've also found out that IDEA doesn't use the -jar vmoption to run the IDE, but it uses its class name. It uses the following command:

```
java -cp <CLASSPATH> com.intellij.idea.Main
```

And I can't find that class in jars.

I have Windows x64.

Comment: Why not use the script that it ships with? Why write your own?

Comment: Because I want it to run on all platforms. I have Windows.

Comment: It already runs on all platforms. Simply download the appropriate version. Intellij, like many IDEs, uses native libraries for much functionality - you cannot simply run a jar.